Carbon::Parse() Problem on some on specific date
I work with Carbon in Laravel framework, and now I have problem.
when I use Carbon::Pars("1403-02-29") it return 1403-03-01.
Carbon::Pars change dates from 1403-02-29 to 1403-02-31 to 1403-03-01
I don't know how to solve it, I used other methods of carbon but didn't work.
I tried other methods of Carbon

It's not Carbon, it's PHP itself, you get the same result with new DateTime('1403-02-29') https://3v4l.org/leXNF and there is nothing to solve here, it's the expected behavior, since this date does not exist it overflows to the next valid date, the happens in many languages.
Since 1403 is 621 years ago, I suspect you're trying to do something rather hacky and maybe it would worth to take one step behind and reconsider the global architecture of the solution rather than trying to hack more to work around this limitation.
